# How to force a user to browse data only by a certain combination of dimensions

Tags: ssas

I have one fact table called "sales" - and two dimensions named "Year", "Type"

I want to disallow the user to browse the data by the "Year" dimension only,
because the aggregated sales by "Year" do not make sense.

Please show me a solution.

Comment: your best bet is to fix the aggregate...the whole point of a cube is to allow users to slice in anyway they want

Answer (score 0):

I guess a simple way would be to combine the two dimensions into one and implement a hierarchy

----- Type
-------- Year

Connect the sales to the above hierarchy and set the **AttributHierarchyEnabled = False** to each field of **type** and **Year**